# Do I need Nginx when deploying my react app to EC2?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, amazon-ec2

Is it necessary/normal to use Nginx when deploying MERN stack app to AWS EC2?

The React app should just need the NodeJS endpoints to be accessible. What is the best way to deploy a react app with nodejs backend to EC2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you dont need Nginx, you can deploy and run directly node app serving react build, you can use any PROCESS MANAGER like PM2 to maintain and monitor the running app.